# Why do I need the limit to be an expression when I calculate surface integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I don't understand (mathmatically) why you sometimes have a whole equation as a limit (surface integral) compared to only a value (line integral), *see yellow markings below.* For instance here when a book in electromagnetics (author: Cheng) calculates following:

> Given $F=(xy,-2x)$ verify Stokes's theorem over a quarter disk with radius 3 in first quadrant.

[image]

Here we calculate a line integral going from A to B in the image above.
[image]

Here we calculate a surface integral over the surface in the image above. $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \longrightarrow x = \sqrt{9-y^2}$
[image]

Comment: Do you understand why you sometimes have a whole expression as a limit of an integral and sometimes don't when taking single and double integrals in simpler contexts that aren't surface or line integrals?

Comment: @MarkS. I don't think I do actually. I know I need these when I have a variable surface to integrate over and not a square of some sort.